# Java Array vs Scala Array

Tags: java, arrays, scala

Seems one difference between Java Array and Scala Array is Java Array is co variant. Scala Array is not. Both are mutable. In java, sort method can take different arrays, such as arrays of String or Int. This is often quoted as a good example of Liskov substitution principle. Seems a good design to me? In Scala we know Array is not co variant. Although Scala Array is designed later than Java. I can't see how Scala Array is better in the aspect of co-variance. It has generic maybe this is better than Java.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you seem to have answered your own question...

Comment: Scala enrichments `Array(1,2,3).find(_ == 2)` but also https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse/issues/126 also http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/arrays.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you look further, you will find that the fathers of the Java language later decided to make Generics **not** covariant. And that is for good reasons.

Because a `List<Apple>` is not a `List<Fruit>`. Otherwise, you could do things like

```
List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<>();
List<Fruit> fruits = apples;
fruits.add(new Banana());
```

but wouldnt you expect that

```
Apple badApple = apples.get(0);
```

is a safe call? If you allow for covariance here, it is not!

And surprise: **that is the problem that Java arrays have!**

Therefore it is really a **problem** that Java arrays are covariant! And it is better that Scala arrays actually allow you to exactly control their "variance". In Scala, you have full control over variance; whereas in Java, they are always covariant.

Having covariant arrays was seen as pragmatic way to allow for "generic" methods like `sort(Object[] objects)` long before anybody thought of having generics in Java. That is almost 20 years in the past. The "modern" way is, as you can see: doing things differently.

The "cost" of this decision is the fact that Java also knows [ArrayStoreException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html). That would not be necessary, if Java arrays would not be covariant!

Comment: It's also worth noting that Scala generics are invariant by default, but can be declared as covariant or contravariant if needed - for example, `scala.collection.Iterrable` is covariant (and Scala collections in general tend to be covariant - I don't know if there are exceptions, other than arrays?). The safety of the variance is checked by the compiler.

Comment: Question was asking java Array but your example was List.

Comment: Lets step back: you asked "what's wrong with covariant arrays". I explained to you the actual problem that **covariant** "collections" have. In other words: "look, lists don't have this problem X here". Do you really need me to tell you "and that means arrays very well have that problem X"?! Together with that comment from @Cyäegha you really got all the information you need! But well, it seems so; thus I updated my answer.

Comment: Calm down. Bro. I am not saying your answer is wrong. Just saying your example could use Array rather than List. In Java Generics are invariant. which would make a different point.

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to come over as rude. I was just kinda surprised by your comment. Thanks for the accept!

Comment: @Cyäegha: `Set`s are invariant for technical reasons. All mutable collections are invariant. In general, it is safe to be covariant, if you can only get things out (e.g. immutable collections, return types of functions, input streams, etc.). It is safe to be contravariant if you can only put things *in* (e.g. loggers, output streams, function parameters, `Comparable`, `Equatable`). That's why e.g. C♯ uses the `in` and `out` keywords for variance. If you can both put things and get things out, the only safe choice is invariance, e.g. mutable collections (including but not limited to `Array`).

Answer (score 0):

scala arrays are mutable.  the array values can be changed to a new value of the same type.  you can not add or remove elements from the scala array without creating a new variable.

val values: Array[Int] = new ArrayInt

or

val values = new ArrayInt